# Cleaning log tables

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm relatively new to magento, i want to run the command

`php -f shell/log.php clean`

in my website root folder.

Can this command affect the performance of the website or delete tables that are crucial ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, This will not affect the performance of your site. This will just clean your `log_customer` and `log_visitor` tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it normal that it is taking a long time(half and hour and still running ..) ?

Comment: with ssh command it should be done fast. you can check the both table size in phpmyadmin. if data is in size GB then it might take a time but not as long you mention.

Comment: Yes it's a little large but half an hour is a long time. It's okay if i stop the process manually ?

Comment: yes you can stop process. also you can manually truncate those tables from phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 3):

Magento provided default functionality in admin side

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log Cleaning
```

You can configure your store to automatically clean up these logs.

OR

. Shell Utility log.php in the ../shell directory

The shell utility log.php can be run manually to clean on-the-fly.

Using the command line tool go to {{MAGENTO_ROOT}}/shell folder and run the following command

```
php -f log.php -- clean
```

By default this will clean the log tables saving log entries for the number of days specified in admin settings under “Log Cleaning”.

You can even specify the days for which you want to save log in the following way
1
    php -f log.php -- clean -- days 10

If you are at the {{MAGENTO_ROOT}} you will be running
view plain
print

```
php -f shell/log.php -- clean -- days 10
```