# How to remove file in session large folder

Tags: magento-1.9

Please help me how to remove file in session large folder (because inodes used is 100%)

This is my problem

```
# du -a /var | sort -n -r | head -n 10
13654960        /var
12763132        /var/www
12278932        /var/www/html
12278928        /var/www/html/magento
11416564        /var/www/html/magento/var
7470108 /var/www/html/magento/var/session
3941824 /var/www/html/magento/var/log
3941820 /var/www/html/magento/var/log/system.log
701992  /var/www/html/magento/media
519024  /var/www/html/magento/media/catalog
```

i can't view file in session folder in ftp

then i run: rm -rf path/var/session/*  but not work.

i think because my session folder is large.

Can i get any  help and suggestion.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94531/cleaning-log-tables/94535#94535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove old files you need to ssh to the server and type this:

```
cd /var/www/html/magento/var/session/
find . -name 'sess*' -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

it will remove files older than week.

to rotate magento logs use this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95489/31999

**UP**
some command variations:

```
find . -mtime +30 -delete
find . -mtime +30 | xargs rm -Rf
```

Comment: Hi MagenX,
This is output when i run:  
/var/www/html/magento/var/session# find . -name 'sess*' -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
find: cannot fork: Cannot allocate memory

please check help me!
Thank you!

Comment: answer updated. see if it helps.

Comment: Now, i get output: fork: Cannot allocate memory when i run any command line. and i can't remove any file on vps. Do you think this is issue ram or disk? Thank you!

Comment: try with a much more consequent number like 1000 instead of 7, and reduce little by little until you reach the desired number of days.